# 404 error in codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I see a lot of this question, but I couldn't solve the issue.

I suspecting that it doesn't read the right segment as I have a reroute config and htaccess to remove the index page.

The code is throwing  a 404 page.

Here is my Model:

```
    public function get_city_reviews($city_id,$limit,$offset) {

    $list = array();

    $this->db->from('biz');

    $this->db->where('city_id',$city_id);

    $this->db->order_by('created_at','desc');

    $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    foreach($query->result() as $row) {

    $list[] = $row;

       }

    return $list;

    }
```

My Controller:

```
         $slug = $this->uri->segment(1,'');
    if($slug)
    {
        $this->load->model('catsAndCities','cc');
        $this->cc->set_table_name('city');
        $city = $this->cc->get($slug,'slug');

        if(!$city || $city->parent_id != 0)
        {
            show_404();
        }
        else 
        {
            $this->tank_auth->set_user_city($city);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        $city = $this->tank_auth->get_user_city();
    }
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config = array();

    $base_url ="local/index/";

    $config["base_url"] = site_url().$base_url;

    $config["total_rows"] = $this->bizs->record_count();

    $config["per_page"] = 5;

    $config["uri_segment"] = 4;

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<p class="pageBar">';

    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</p>';

    $config['num_links'] =2;

    $config['anchor_class'] = 'class="page-num" ';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;

    $data["results"] = $this->bizs->get_city_reviews($city->id,$config["per_page"],  
    $page);

    $data["pagination_links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['reviews'] =  $data["results"];

    $this->load->view('local/index',$data);
```

My View:

```
    <div id="pagination-container">
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>

       <?=$pagination_links?>

    </ul>
    </div>
```

This is my Routes:

```
   $route['default_controller'] = "local/city";
   $route['[0-9a-zA-Z\-_]+'] = "local/city";
   $route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";
```

This is my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>


ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i suspected, you are telling CI to find 404 page if no city is found. Try commenting this : Or find a way to work around it.

```
     if(!$city || $city->parent_id != 0)
    {
        show_404();
    }
    else 
    {
        $this->tank_auth->set_user_city($city);
    }
```

Then change

```
   $base_url ="local/index/";
```

to

```
   $base_url ="";
```

And your segment to 1

```
  $config["uri_segment"] = 1;
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the base_url to "local/city", and the uri_segment changed to 3.

Comment: @Winterrain That's the same thing. 404 page.

Comment: Actually, which url is throwing the 404? Does the default page 1 work, or you are only getting 404 with the page2,3,etc.

Comment: first page works, I am getting the limit I wanted, but the rest throw the 404.

Comment: are you accessing the first page using /local/index/ or /local/city/ ?

Comment: That's my home page, so I just go localhost/ci. The first page returns the number of rows I wanted, but the other links just go to 404. Even if I try do localhost/ci/local/city it throws 404. I think it has to do with routes

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code. Are you that's all the code you have in local/index?